# https redirect to another page though SSL certificate is installed properly

Tags: wordpress, http, redirect, ssl, https

I would like to tell you first that I have installed SSL certificate to my wordpress website and website working fine on http://www.example.com ,but I want to redirect on https://www.example.com . When I open the website with https it go to another page that shows me

> "Future home of something quite cool.
>  If you're the site owner, log in
>   to launch this site
>  If you are a visitor, check back soon."

I had conversation with technical support and they replied that there is some redirection issue with the website. There is no redirect set up for the website from Hosting.
please guide me or instruct me regarding this.Thanks in advance :)
regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to show a different page for http and https, depending on your webserver configuration. Ask your web hosting provider to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

When I use HTTPS in Wordpress I usually use this plugin [Easy HTTPS Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/https-redirection/).
You can try to install it but, watching to your explanation, it seems to be an error of the provider

Comment: I have installed the plugin that you mentioned above.My whole website and wordpress Dashboard stop working.I have deleted the plugin from Cpanel but nothing works.
Please help me